# Why are my global variables not storing across different activities?

Tags: android

I have setup a Java class that holds various global variables:

```
class GlobalClass extends Application {
int global_counter;

String FileNameSmall[] = {"simage2", "simage1", "simage3"};
String FileName[] = {"image2", "image1", "image3"};
String Answers[] = {"blah1", "blah2", "blah3"};     
}
```

The global counter is to count through the arrays. When I update it in one activity:

```
GlobalClass global = new GlobalClass();
global.global_counter = global.global_counter + 1;
```

It works fine in that activity. Yet if I start a new activity with a new XML format etc. then declare the use of the global variable it doesn't return the appended amount its returned to 0.

Im still new to all this java so please be patient. Am i missing something fundamental like a reference in the android manifest for my global glass or do i have to declare the globalClass global=newGlobal(); in the extends activity class?

Any help would be great

Cheers

Comment: This is how you use the `Application` class to store state: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android

Comment: This is the problem --> `GlobalClass global = new GlobalClass();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your variables as `static` members. That way they have the same values across the whole application:

```
public static int global_counter;

public static String FileNameSmall[] = {"simage2", "simage1", "simage3"};
public static String FileName[] = {"image2", "image1", "image3"};
public static String Answers[] = {"blah1", "blah2", "blah3"};
```

**p.s.:** you could also follow the Java Singleton pattern to have one `GlobalClass` instance or pass the first created intance from one activity to the next one.

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

Comment: Thank you ... i knew i was missing something silly... static has done the trick ... although now its caused other issues lol. But i know whats happening there. Im sure static was used in an earlier language like ada to mean a constant.. maybe thats why i kept away from it. Thanks again

Comment: Gotta love the experts that know it all and give -points to people who are new and who do search the web but get in a bit of a muddle about whats going on. Thanks for that.

Comment: I'm happy to help! Note, that generally a Singleton is - from an architectual point of view - the better way to implement this. It's not recommended to extend/use the `Application` class (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html). For more information about Singletons check for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern. :-)

Comment: Thank you i will look into that as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass any variable or information between Activities using `Activity.putExtra` like in this example when the user clicks a button that creates a new screen and display it:

```
 startForm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if ((!selectedFormCode.equalsIgnoreCase("")) && (!userCode.getText().toString().equals("")))
                {
                    Intent questionScreen = new Intent();
                    questionScreen.setClassName("com.android.artemis", "com.android.artemis.QuestionScreen");

                    func.ShowMessage("Loading Screen...");

                    // send preview config to next screen
                    questionScreen.putExtra("formProperties", formProperties.toString()); 
                    questionScreen.putExtra("selectedFormCode", selectedFormCode);
                    questionScreen.putExtra("selectedRegionCode", selectedRegionCode);
                    questionScreen.putExtra("selectedSubRegionCode", selectedSubRegionCode);
                    questionScreen.putExtra("selectedRegionLabel", selectedRegionLabel);
                    questionScreen.putExtra("selectedSubRegionLabel", selectedSubRegionLabel);
                    questionScreen.putExtra("userRegistrationCode", userCode.getText().toString());

                    startForm.setEnabled(false); // evita que o usuário clique mais de uma vez

                    startActivity(questionScreen);

                    startForm.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    func.ShowMessage("Complete todas as Informações antes de Continuar!");
                }
            }
        });
```

This way you send only the information that the next screen you use.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure of the following things:

1. Your `Application` extension class (`GlobalClass`) is referenced inside your manifest XML like so: `<application android:name=".GlobalClass">`
2. When you need to get a reference to your Application object, run the function `getApplication()` from your activity. You can cast this to `GlobalClass`. Creating a new instance of it manually is incorrect (`GlobalClass global = new GlobalClass()`).
3. Your application object is a singleton, so your variables don't need to be static.
4. If you don't want to use the system's Application object mechanism, google the term `singleton` and implement one. A singleton is a global object accessible anywhere which has a single instance and can hold global variables.